# Salesforce Email Servers and Outlook - Calendar Sync

Tags: email, calendar, outlook, salesforce-for-outlook

I am designing a solution to sync Salesforce calendar events with Outlook calendar. I already have explored Salesforce for Outlook plug in; however business considers that as a secondary solution as it requires a plug-in to be installed.

I am currently trying to find if Outlook can be configured to pull Calendar Events from Salesforce Email servers. Appreciate any pointers in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Implisit](http://www.implisit.com). Implisit connects directly to your email server as well as your Salesforce (**no plugin installation required**), and enters all relevant emails and calendar events into Salesforce - **fully automatically**, attaching them to Opportunities, Accounts, Contacts and Leads.

DISCLAMER: I work for Implisit.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy idea - you could create a custom Visualforce page in a Site that publishes the information in the iCal format. Then have Outlook subscribe to that.

You would need to give some consideration on how to secure the data.

Comment: Just looking for a solution with Outlook. Since Outlook is an Email Client, wondering why can't it be configured to pull Calendar Events from Salesforce Email Servers?

Comment: I don't believe Salesforce will give you that type of access to their servers. They expect you to use the "Salesforce for Outlook" plugin.